# Native crash of Android because of Camera in pre-launch report in Google Play Console

Tags: android, flutter, camera, prelaunch

Having only a single Samsung test device on my own I am unable to reproduce the following crash of my flutter app happening on a Google Pixel 7 device (Android SDK 33) in an automated pre-launch test in Google Play Console. It is an issue of the camera provider.

I am using the camera preview. The issue seems to happen when the camera is started since the screen displayed in pre-lauch report video stays black.
The version of the flutter camera widget is `camera: ^0.10.5+9` which is the latst release.

I could not find an Issue on Github and I am unable to reproduce this error. When I use an emulated Pixel 7 with SDK 33 I dont get this error.

Would be happy for any solution or tips on this or a possible reason why this is happening.

```
Native crash of /apex/com.google.pixel.camera.hal/bin/hw/android.hardware.camera.provider@2.7-service-google

03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318): Revision: 'MP1.0'
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318): ABI: 'arm64'
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318): Timestamp: 2024-03-16 07:13:05.861135246-0700
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318): Process uptime: 0s
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318): Cmdline: /apex/com.google.pixel.camera.hal/bin/hw/android.hardware.camera.provider@2.7-service-google
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318): pid: 755, tid: 25279, name: SegmenterFirstF  >>> /apex/com.google.pixel.camera.hal/bin/hw/android.hardware.camera.provider@2.7-service-google <<<
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318): uid: 1000
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318): tagged_addr_ctrl: 0000000000000001 (PR_TAGGED_ADDR_ENABLE)
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318): Abort message: 'F0000 00:00:1710598385.750268   25279 xeno_dsp_segmenter.cc:289] Check failed: prev_mask_gxp_buffer is OK (INTERNAL: Failed to map buffer.
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318): === Source Location Trace: === 
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318): hardware/gchips/pnp/apps/camera/dsp/gxp_buffer_pool.cc:114
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318): ) Failed to get prev mask gxp buffer.'
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318):     x0  0000000000000000  x1  00000000000062bf  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000007142b456d0
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318):     x4  1f1eff092d666d68  x5  1f1eff092d666d68  x6  1f1eff092d666d68  x7  7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318):     x8  00000000000000f0  x9  00000074418409e0  x10 0000000000000001  x11 0000007441882370
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318):     x12 0000007142b44390  x13 000000000000000e  x14 0000007142b44440  x15 00000014852d1f50
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318):     x16 00000074418efd50  x17 00000074418caeb0  x18 000000711030a000  x19 00000000000002f3
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318):     x20 00000000000062bf  x21 00000000ffffffff  x22 b40000724d186430  x23 b4000071cd1bcff0
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318):     x24 b4000071cd1c06b0  x25 0000007142b45cb0  x26 0000007142b45ff8  x27 00000000001ec000
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318):     x28 00000000002ed000  x29 0000007142b45750
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318):     lr  00000074418721c8  sp  0000007142b456b0  pc  00000074418721f4  pst 0000000000001000
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318): backtrace:
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318):       #00 pc 00000000000531f4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+164) (BuildId: dc4001c2ef2dfc23467040797a96840c)
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318):       #01 pc 000000000166b26c  /apex/com.google.pixel.camera.hal/lib64/libgoog_catpipe.so (absl::log_internal::LogMessage::FailWithoutStackTrace()+48) (BuildId: a529a9ce985900415d5ff56466a5bbea)
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318):       #02 pc 000000000166b5b4  /apex/com.google.pixel.camera.hal/lib64/libgoog_catpipe.so (absl::log_internal::LogMessage::SendToLog()+124) (BuildId: a529a9ce985900415d5ff56466a5bbea)
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318):       #03 pc 000000000166b034  /apex/com.google.pixel.camera.hal/lib64/libgoog_catpipe.so (absl::log_internal::LogMessage::Flush()+304) (BuildId: a529a9ce985900415d5ff56466a5bbea)
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318):       #04 pc 000000000166b864  /apex/com.google.pixel.camera.hal/lib64/libgoog_catpipe.so (absl::log_internal::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()+4) (BuildId: a529a9ce985900415d5ff56466a5bbea)
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318):       #05 pc 000000000068830c  /apex/com.google.pixel.camera.hal/lib64/libgoog_catpipe.so (wireless_android_camera::rectiface::XenoDspSegmenter::Initialize()+1968) (BuildId: a529a9ce985900415d5ff56466a5bbea)
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318):       #06 pc 0000000000687afc  /apex/com.google.pixel.camera.hal/lib64/libgoog_catpipe.so (wireless_android_camera::rectiface::CreateXenoDspSegmenter(wireless_android_camera::rectiface::XenoSegmenterOptions const&, wireless_android_camera::common::CommonCodeTimer*, GxpCapi_DevicePowerState)+224) (BuildId: a529a9ce985900415d5ff56466a5bbea)
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318):       #07 pc 000000000067df3c  /apex/com.google.pixel.camera.hal/lib64/libgoog_catpipe.so (wireless_android_camera::catpipe::(anonymous namespace)::CreateXenoSegmenter(wireless_android_camera::common::Vector<int, 2>)+112) (BuildId: a529a9ce985900415d5ff56466a5bbea)
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318):       #08 pc 000000000067dc78  /apex/com.google.pixel.camera.hal/lib64/libgoog_catpipe.so (void absl::internal_any_invocable::LocalInvoker<false, void, wireless_android_camera::catpipe::(anonymous namespace)::MaybeRunWakeupInferenceAsync()::$_3&&>(absl::internal_any_invocable::TypeErasedState*)+36) (BuildId: a529a9ce985900415d5ff56466a5bbea)
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318):       #09 pc 0000000001334f70  /apex/com.google.pixel.camera.hal/lib64/libgoog_catpipe.so (util::functional::internal::FunctorCallback<Closure, false, absl::AnyInvocable<void () &&>, void ()>::Run()+36) (BuildId: a529a9ce985900415d5ff56466a5bbea)
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318):       #10 pc 000000000133e2bc  /apex/com.google.pixel.camera.hal/lib64/libgoog_catpipe.so (ThreadPoolWorker::Run()+356) (BuildId: a529a9ce985900415d5ff56466a5bbea)
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318):       #11 pc 000000000133a818  /apex/com.google.pixel.camera.hal/lib64/libgoog_catpipe.so (Thread::ThreadBody(void*)+456) (BuildId: a529a9ce985900415d5ff56466a5bbea)
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318):       #12 pc 00000000000c226c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+204) (BuildId: dc4001c2ef2dfc23467040797a96840c)
03-16 07:13:06.132: F/DEBUG(25318):       #13 pc 0000000000054a30  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: dc4001c2ef2dfc23467040797a96840c)
03-16 07:13:06.146: W/NativeCrashListener(1386): Couldn't find ProcessRecord for pid 755
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Give this A Try , Thus Camera plugin Uses Native Codes `Kotlin` for Camera

```
cd android
```

And  `./gradlew clean`  and Build the Apk

The Crash can happen when the build Gradle is not synced properly

Comment: This crash didnt happen on Samsung but on a Google Pixel Device. Also my Min SDK version is 26. This is definitely not the issue. Also I tested with an emulator on pixel using the SDK as in the Google Play Console test and could not reproduce the issue

Comment: Please let me know your flutter and dart sdk versions

Comment: Flutter 3.16.9 Dart 3.2.6

Comment: Updated the Answer please give it a try